# Запретить массовое выделение мышкой в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет.Подскажите как можно сделать массовое выделение используя только Shift и Ctrl.На данный момент массово можно выделить строки зажатой мышкой по datagridview,shift,ctrl.Как можно запретить массовое выделение мышкой?

Comment: Ну и зачем это надо?

Comment: К сожалению долго объяснять но так требуется.((

Comment: Так запретить или сделать?

Comment: Запретить массовое выделение мышкой.

Comment: Вангую, что вы криво реализовали Drag&Drop (вместо перетаскивания получается выделение) и пытаетесь подпереть костыликом. Нэ? И, кстати, на en.so вы вопрос задали понятней.

Comment: Drag&drop я вообще не использую

Comment: Winform.Обыскал все но решения не нашел.

Comment: Не успел проверить, ну в общем идея такова. Нужно подписаться на событие для грида MouseUp или SelectedCellsChanged или может MouseLeftButtonUp. Отлавливать нажатие клавиш var keys = System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys; if (keys == Keys.Shift) и управлять выборкой с кода. Фильтр (sender as DataGrid).SelectedItems

Comment: Либо не понял суть либо так не получается)(

Comment: К тому же у datagridview нет свойства Selecteditems,а свойство selectedrows доступно только для чтения

Comment: MouseLeftButtonUp так же нет в свойствах у datagridview

Answer (score 1):

У DataGridView есть специальное свойство MultiSelect. Делаешь его в False и все.

Если нужно заблокировать взаимодействие с мышкой, то можно в событии CellMouseClick перехватывать и нажатие и ничего не делать.

Comment: Не помогло.Всеравно выделяется мышкой.

Comment: @ლუკაბერიანიძე - `ListBox` при заданном `MultiExtended` позволяет выделять элементы движением мышки. Так что определитесь, что же вам нужно.

Comment: Прошу прощения,ошибся)